# html email issues with layout

Tags: html, gmail, tablelayout, html-email

I haven't had to send any mailshots for a number of years and I remember the process to be very painful then.

I have cut up my design into three sections and placed them within a table the table has a height and width defined and so do all the individual  elements, however when viewed in an email client such as Gmail there are spaces between the three table rows.

My html. I think you'll agree it couldn't be more simplified!

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" height="550">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550" height="104">
<img src="images/OC_01.gif" alt="" width="550" height="104"></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="246" height="341">
<img src="images/OC_02.gif" alt="" width="246" height="341"></td>
  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="304" height="341">
<img src="images/OC_03.gif" alt="" width="304" height="341"></td>
 </tr><tr>
<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#014280" width="550" height="105" valign="top">
<a href="TBA"><img src="images/OC_04.gif" alt="" width="550" height="105"></a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Is there anyone here today that has enough email html experience to point me in the right direction?

Edit to add: I have been dissecting some commercial emails that have been sent to me in the past and I have found that some of them also have this weird spacing issue in Gmail. I have also noticed that each has been designed in such a way as to accommodate any extra spacing between the rows so I'm going to assume that the answer to this question is to ensure that the design is produced in such a way that these gaps are not an issue.

Comment: there is a tr that's not closed properly. First row, is that a typo? You are also not closing the table tag.

Comment: I see what you mean by the unclosed tags however this seems to be an error when I pasted the html into the message above on my original the TR tag is closed on the next line before the next opening TR and I do have a closing <table> tag. Sorry about the poor cut and paste job. I shall update the opening post with a better representation.

Comment: what happens if you take out the height attribute from the table itself and the columns? Let the height get determined automatically

Comment: Sadly nothing at all, it still breaks.

Comment: Try closing the image tags: http://jsfiddle.net/dpTqH

Comment: Thanks, it was worth a try but unfortunately didn't stop the layout from breaking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5956/discussion-between-seannieuwoudt-and-andrew)

Answer (score 2):

You must include style="display:block" with all images to prevent the gap issue in various email clients.

Example:

```
<img src="http://www.website.com/images/kitty.jpg" alt="Picture of Kitty" 
 width="1000" height="1000" 
 style="border:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; **display:block;**"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following attribute to the **IMG** element:

```
style="display: block;"
```

I've added it for you http://jsfiddle.net/xE9Qr/

Default IMG **display** is **inline-block** which produces unwanted space after.

I've tested it using http://ctrlq.org/html-mail/ and the spaces between TR elements are gone now. Remeber to see the result you have to send HTML table layout email to your gMail account.

Comment: Hi, I thought that this might have been it, but when you send the actual email I still get the spacing issue in Gmail. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: What browser do you use? Also screenshot would be nice.

Comment: I've also had to use font-size:0 along with this in order for it to work.

Comment: It works fine in a browser, it just messes up in Gmail. Also, I have tried to set the font-size to 0 using an inline style which again didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding align="top" to images seems to be a potential fix:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <img src="images/OC_01.gif" alt="" width="550" height="104" align="top"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="246">
    <img src="images/OC_02.gif" alt="" width="246" height="341" align="top" />
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/OC_03.gif" alt="" width="304" height="341" align="top" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#014280">
    <a href="addlater"><img src="images/OC_04.gif" alt="" width="550" height="105" align="top" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly does the fiddle accomplish?

Comment: Frustratingly, this also didn't work in gmail. But well worth a shot.